# Hide/Show from left

Tags: jquery, html

I have this code with which I can hide/show. I want the div to hide while it moves left. How can I do that? [This is what I have FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dRpWv/306/)

### JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#button").toggle(function() {
        $(this).text('Show Content');
    }, function() {
        $(this).text('Hide Content');
    }).click(function(){
        $("#hidden_content").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

### HTML

```
<a href="#" id="button" class="button_style">Hide content</a>
<div id="hidden_content">Content</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by *I want the div to hide while it moves left*?

Comment: Now, it is moving up. I want it to move left.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) with the `width` set to [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animation-properties).

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/dRpWv/309/)

```
$("#hidden_content").animate({width: 'toggle'}, "slow");
```

- P.S - Notice I've added a CSS setting that changes *`#hidden_content`*'s display to `inline-block`, because the default width of a *div* (a *block* element) is 100% and the animation is kind of weird that way.

---

> ## [Animation Properties and Values](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animation-properties)
>
> ...
>
> In addition to numeric values, each property can take the strings
> 'show', 'hide', and '**toggle**'. These shortcuts allow for custom
> hiding and showing animations that take into account the display type
> of the element. In order to use jQuery's built-in toggle state
> tracking, the 'toggle' keyword must be consistently given as the value
> of the property being animated.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how would you blind it out to the right?

Comment: @Vineeth The simplest way would be to set the `text-direction` in the CSS to [right to left](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/dRpWv/312/).

Answer (score 3):

You can do it this way:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#button").toggle(function() {
        $(this).text('Show Content');
        $("#hidden_content").animate({left: "-50px"}, 500);        
    }, function() {
        $(this).text('Hide Content');
        $("#hidden_content").animate({left: "0px"}, 500);
    })
});
```

Demo [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dRpWv/310/)

Answer (score 0):

you can be use slide effect of jquery Ui. 
http://api.jqueryui.com/slide-effect/