# JS .show .hide direction

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this function:

```
$('.Show').click(function() {
    $('#mobile-nb-c').show(500);
    $('.Show').hide(500);
    $('.Hide').show(500);
});
```

This function opens my div like this: [image: show/hide img1]

But I would like it to make it open like this: [image: show/hide img2]

Can this be done?

Comment: Read about the [`animate`](https://api.jquery.com/animate/) function

Comment: This may help -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521291/jquery-slide-left-and-show

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide/Show from left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18887449/hide-show-from-left)

Comment: This is also specifically a JQuery feature, not general JavaScript

Comment: those images make your post overly big, you could do the same with ascii art, please remove them...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`show()` and `hide()` both do not have any animation properties related to them. They will just hide an element or show it. You can use `.animate()` for using all sorts of animations

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.Show').animate({ width: <yourWidth> }, 600)
$('.Hide').animate({ width: 0 }, 600)
```